# Automate whitelisting ip addresses in iptables via bash

Tags: linux, bash, iptables

I am looking for the best way to automate whitelisting IP addresses into `iptables`. The list of ip addresses and ports comes from a JSON file `/accept-rules.json` which is formatted like:

```
[
  {
    "ip": "1.2.3.4",
    "cidr": 32,
    "protocol": "tcp",
    "port": 3306
  },
  {
    "ip": "2.4.5.6",
    "cidr": 32,
    "protocol": "tcp",
    "port": 80
  },
  {
    "ip": "5.6.7.8",
    "cidr": 32,
    "protocol": "tcp",
    "port": 443
  },
  {
    "ip": "6.8.3.1",
    "cidr": 32,
    "protocol": "tcp",
    "port": 53
  }
]
```

I need a `bash` or `python` script which reads the json file and creates `ACCEPT` iptables rules. Example `ACCEPT` rules based on the `json` above should look like:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 1.2.3.4/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 2.4.5.6/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 5.6.7.8/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 6.8.3.1/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
```

Any idea of the best way to code this up?

Comment: Why Bash? This would be much easier to code in Python or Perl or any other language which has JSON support.

Comment: Do you really want this to be in bash?

Comment: `bash` would be best, but agree, Python is probably the best suited. Python is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `iptables -A` adds rules to the end of the table. When matching rules, iptables works from top to bottom and the first match wins so if you had previously blocked an address then white listing it with `-A` won't work (many default rulesets hav a blaket reject all at the end for example) It's better to use `iptables -I` to insert rules at the begining in this case.

```
#!/bin/bash

function getval {
    set -- $1
    RET=${2//[\",]/}
}
while read line
    do
        set -- $line
        if [[ "$1" == '"ip":' ]]
            then
                getval "$line"
                IPADDRESS=$RET
                read line
                getval "$line"
                CIDR=$RET
                read line
                getval  "$line"
                PROTOCOL=$RET
                read line
                getval "$line"
                PORT=$RET
                /sbin/iptables  -I INPUT -s "$IPADDRESS"/"$CIDR" -p "$PROTOCOL" -m "$PROTOCOL" --dport "$PORT" -j ACCEPT
             fi
    done <file.json
```

Comment: Keep `eval` out, use `${2//[\",]*/}` !

Comment: Which leads to the next problem, the list of ip addresses in `/accept-rules.json` changes frequently. I was thinking of simply calling `iptables -F` which deletes all rules before execution, but then my default rules that are not in `/accept-rules.json` would not get created. Any ideas how to solve this problem? Basically I want to be able to call this script multiple times a day, but only have it insert or delete changes reflected in `/accept-rules.json`. Is there a way to create a group in iptables and then flush all rules in that group only?

Comment: @Justin This is not same question, please fork a new one... and let us see what you've already tried!

Comment: Looks like creating a chain for the accept rules and then flushing that chain is what I want. I am going to experiment. Thanks.

Comment: This version require that field are always in same order, so it's not really *json compatible*

Comment: @F.Hauri: `*` not required the ip address and protocol end up "" with it.

Answer (score 2):

### Pure [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) based on syntax provided

There is a cleaner *pure bash* version. (without `eval`)

```
declare -A iptArray
iptArray[action]='A'
getval() {
    [[ "$@" =~  \"([^\*]*)\"\ *:\ *\"?([^\",]*)\"?[,\ ]*$ ]] && \
        iptArray[${BASH_REMATCH[1]}]=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
}
while read line;do
    getval $line
    [[ "$line" =~ } ]] && \
        echo iptables -${iptArray[action]} INPUT -p ${iptArray[protocol]} \
            -s ${iptArray[ip]}/${iptArray[cidr]} \
            --dport ${iptArray[port]} -j ACCEPT
  done < ipt_whitelist.json 
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 1.2.3.4/32 --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 2.4.5.6/32 --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 5.6.7.8/32 --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 6.8.3.1/32 --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
```

(Delete `echo` for doing action instead of just printing it)

### Working over [json](/questions/tagged/json) under [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), using `jq` tool

As you know have to found values named `protocol`, `ip`, `cidr` and `port` in each field, you could ensure ordering and extract values by using `jq` in something like:

```
i=0
while :;do
    for var in proto ip mlen port ;do
        read -r $var
        [ "${!var}" = "null" ] && break 2
    done < <(
      jq -r ".[$i].protocol,.[$i].ip,.[$i].cidr,.[$i].port" <whitelist.json
    )
    echo iptables -A INPUT -p $proto -s $ip/$mlen -dport $port -j ACCEPT
    ((i++))
done
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 1.2.3.4/32 -dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 2.4.5.6/32 -dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 5.6.7.8/32 -dport 443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 6.8.3.1/32 -dport 53 -j ACCEPT
```

(Again: Delete `echo` for doing action instead of just printing it)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a python code:

This will generate a bash script file 'accept.sh' with all the iptable entries.

```
# accept.py

fp = open("accept-rules.json", "r")

data = fp.readlines()
fp1 = open("accept.sh", "w")

for line in data:

    if "{" in line:
        datum = {}
    elif "}" in line:
        s = "iptables -A INPUT -s " + datum["ip"] + "/" + datum["cidr"] + " -p " + datum["protocol"] + " -m " + datum["protocol"] + " --dport " + datum["port"] + " -j ACCEPT\n"
        fp1.write(s)
    elif "[" in line or "]" in line:
        continue
    else:
        datum[line.split(":")[0].strip().strip('"')] = line.split(":")[1].strip().strip(",").strip('"')

fp1.close()
fp.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner Python version:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import json
import sys

for rule in json.load(sys.stdin):
    print("iptables -I INPUT -s {ip}/{cidr} -p {protocol} "
          "-m {protocol} --dport {port} -j ACCEPT".format(**rule))
```

Note: It uses `-I` to insert rules at the beginning.

#### Example

```
$ json2iptables < accept-rules.json
```

#### [Output](http://ideone.com/fYvc6t)

```
iptables -I INPUT -s 1.2.3.4/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -s 2.4.5.6/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -s 5.6.7.8/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -s 6.8.3.1/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 0):

Python implementation:

```
import json
rules_file = open('accept-rules.json', 'r')
rules = json.load(rules_file)
rules_file.close()
iptables = open('iptavles.sh', 'w')
for rule in rules:
    rule_str = 'iptables -A INPUT -s %s/%s -p tcp -m %s --dport %s -j ACCEPT\n' % (rule['ip'], rule['cidr'], rule['protocol'], rule['port'])
    iptables.write(rule_str)
iptables.close()
```

accept-rules.json - start json file,
iptables.sh - goal file